# What is the PersistenceProvider class for TomEE 9.0?

Tags: jpa, apache-tomee

I am creating a new application for TomEE 9.0. I have a simple JPA application that needs to connect to the database. I get the following error:

```
Nov 17, 2021 10:51:22 AM jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
WARNING: jakarta.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
```

What must the provider in the persistence.xml be for TomEE 9.0-targeted projects?

Comment: The exception in the question is raised while running on Tom EE with no provider specified in the persistence.xml file. What should the provider be for Jakarta Persistence 3.0?

Comment: @BalusC I clearly understand what JEE is. My question remains valid. Please refer to my previous comment.

Comment: Which JPA impl do you want to use?.

Comment: I want to use the eclipse implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment, you want to use EclipseLink as JPA Provider. The required provider class can be found in the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/3.0/solutions/testingjpa002.htm) of Eclipse Link 3.0 and is

```
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
```

Therefore, you need to add the related dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In addition, you need to specific the JPA provider class via  in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```